# How to set value on page load using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have to set dynamically text value when page was load. The code is..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Function call
    setname();
});

function setname() {
  document.getElementById('loginname').value = localStorage.getItem("username");
}
```

```html
<span class="text-muted text-xs block" id="loginname"></span>
```

I get value from my local session but why they are not set on my `loginname` field? I don't know why, please help me.

Comment: Could you perhaps include your form? - And why is this tagged as PHP?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've shown. Does the `loginname` element exist in the DOM on load? Is the `username` value set in localStorage?

Comment: <span class="text-muted text-xs block" id="loginname"> </span>

Comment: @piyush put this statement `alert(localStorage.getItem("username"))`;  in `setname()` see what you get.

Comment: document.getElementById('loginname').innerHTML= localStorage.getItem("username");

Comment: i will try it and update you as soon.

Answer (score 6):

`span` elements do not have a `value` property - you need to set `innerText`:

```
function setname() {
    document.getElementById('loginname').innerText = localStorage.getItem("username");
}
```

Alternatively, you can use jQuery exclusively:

```
$(function() {
    $('#loginname').text(localStorage.getItem('username'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 4):

Try using the jquery operators to set the value:

EDIT: appearantly span doesn't have the val attribute instead you need to set the text attribute, edited in solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Function call
    setname();
});

function setname() {
    $('#loginname').text(localStorage.getItem("username"));
}
```

Comment: could you guys please give me feedback as to why you downvote this? this is how I do it so is there something wrong with it?

Comment: It's been downvoted because the `val()` method is for use on elements which have a `value` property, which `span` do not.

Comment: The reason _I_ down voted was/is because as stated in the other answers, spans doesn't have a value and should use innterText instead, secondly, the code OP used wasn't wrong as such, so changeing to jQuery wouldn't have solved the issue.

Comment: When I was writing this answer there were no other answers and I didn't know about spans not having val but it's been edited now :D

Answer (score 4):

Since it is  `span` elements so you can not have `value` property for it.you need to set `innerText`:

```
function setname() {
    document.getElementById('loginname').innerText = localStorage.getItem("username");
}
```

You can do it through `innerHTML` also like this:-

```
function setname() {
    document.getElementById('loginname').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("username");
}
```